# TS2684 with HttpClient response in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

Just updated from Angular5 to Angular7 and while converting old RxJS syntax to new I am stuck with this error. Here is the code:

```
     return this.http.request( reqOptions )
        .pipe( 
            map( (resp: HttpResponse<any>) => resp.body )
        );
```

I get the map(...) line underlined with TS Error which says

```
The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<HttpResponse<any>>'.ts(2684)
```

- Angular CLI V 7.3.7
- Angular Core V 7.2.11
- RxJS V 6.4.0
- RxJsCompat V 6.4.0
- TypeScript V 3.2.4
- IDE: VS Code

What's the deal?

PS. Just checked a different project running same major versions of those libraries with WebStorm and while having the same syntax AND virtually the same `tsconfig` files, I don't get any type errors there?...

Comment: try putting <any> after .request

Comment: thanks, but nope, didn't help

Comment: maybe your method declaration is off oO

Comment: `Observable<any>` ?

Comment: hm seems alright possible alternatives : you forgot to save (the compile is still compiling 'return this') there might also be another return (I dont know) but the code example you prvided seems alright

Comment: argghh! it was a falsy import. need to import from `rxjs/operators not from rxjs-compat/operator/map